# Angular2 compatibility check on older Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular, browser-support

Is there a way to check if the current build of Angular 2 is fully compatible with my current version of Chrome (which is not the latest) ? Otherwise I would like to check if older stable builds are supported. My Chrome version is 30 and cannot be upgraded due to a certain policy.

I am looking for something similar to:

1. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/
2. https://html5test.com/

It would be sufficient to see if the Angular2 build crashes or not.

Comment: I have used the is.js library to check for browser version. It's really easy to use. Link: https://github.com/arasatasaygin/is.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my version of Chome supports Angular 2.

1. I have visited http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/ using Chrome 30 and found out that it supports most of es5 features (that's 96% which is more than IE9, which has official support from ng team).
2. I have downloaded the final step and most complete angular tutorial project (the link at current date is https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) and started it with `npm install` and then `npm start` and then access the link from terminal using my older version of Chrome.

I would recommend you to also search for some more advanced angular2 projects on github, that you could download and start in order to check for other topics.